# layout on home page and positioning of products on home page

Tags: onepage-checkout, home, onestepcheckout

Hi i'm working on website called headsetsindia.com i want to do some changes on this site how can i...?

How to align submit button on checkout page so that person entring the values should not drag the page to rite to click submit button.

How to change the position(Sequence) of products to be displayed on home page in magento

Answer (score 1):

You should have a css file attached to the website you should be able to change styling elements, like width, positions and much more in there. If you do not know what CSS file you are looking for or where to find the CSS for that button. Right click and click inspect element this should give you an idea of where to find the file.